# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<SourceSystemConfig>

Tags: java

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<SourceSystemConfig>
```

when is doing like this i'm seeing that warrning i don't want to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` so i tried diffrent way

i tried with wild card `Map<?,?>` and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

```
private SourceSystemConfig getSourceConfig(HttpServletRequest request, SourceProjectAssocation sourceSystem) throws Exception
{
            //Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<SourceSystemConfig>
    List<SourceSystemConfig> sourceSystemList = (List<SourceSystemConfig>) request.getSession()
            .getAttribute(SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIST);
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sourceSystemList))
    {
        UserEntity userEntity = vendorUtils.getUserDetails(request.getRemoteUser());
        sourceSystemList =  vendorUtils.getVendorConnectionsForTenant(userEntity);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIST, sourceSystemList);
    }
    Optional<SourceSystemConfig> source = sourceSystemList.stream()
            .filter(ss -> ss.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(sourceSystem.getKey())).findFirst();
    SourceSystemConfig config = null;
    if (source.isPresent())
    {
        config = source.get();
    }
    return config;
}

List<SourceSystemConfig>
    List<SourceSystemConfig> sourceSystemList = (List<SourceSystemConfig>) request.getSession()
            .getAttribute(SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIST);
//Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<SourceSystemConfig> i am getting this warnning but i don't expected this
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply store a `SourceSystemConfig[]` or your own serializable class that holds a `List<SourceSystemConfig>`.

```
List<SourceSystemConfig> sourceSystemList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(sourceSystemList, (SourceSystemConfig[]) request.getSession()
        .getAttribute(SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIST));
```

This avoids a cast for a class with generic parameter types. The cast `(SourceSystemConfig[])` can be done immediately & correctly.